# NCache Generic Type Handler Implementation

Tags: .net, ncache

In NCache Manager for every Cache you have to define compact type seperatly in case of generic Is there any way to provide all the classes at once to Cache Compact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should implement Ncache IGenericTypeProvider Interface from Runtime.dll
 class GenericTypeProvider1 : IGenericTypeProvider
    {
        #region IGenericTypeProvider Members

```
    public Type[] GetGenericTypes()
    {
        ArrayList aryList = new ArrayList();

        #region Classes that hold generic types inside or inherited from the generic types...
        aryList.Add(new PrimitiveTypes());
        aryList.Add(new ComplexTypes());
        aryList.Add(new UnsignedTypes());
        aryList.Add(new GenericHolder());
        aryList.Add(new GenericChild()); 
        #endregion

        #region Custom Generic objects that take only one type arguemt ...
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<string>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<bool>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<double>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<byte[]>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<DateTime>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<TimeSpan>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<Guid>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<Product>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<AllTypes>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<NullableObject>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<List<AllTypes>>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<List<AllDataTypes>>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<List<NullableObject>>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<Dictionary<string, NullableObject>>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<List<GenericList<NullableObject>>>());
        aryList.Add(new GenericClass<List<Dictionary<string, NullableObject>>>()); 
        #endregion

        //--- Populate the type array with the types of the above given objects ...
        Type[] types = new Type[aryList.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
            types[i] = aryList[i].GetType();


        return types;
    }
```